# Typescript ошибка типов

Tags: reactjs, typescript

у меня есть страница с модальным окном, в котором я должен выбрать аудио файл и передать его в качестве аргумента в функцию. компилятор выдает такую ошибку

> Argument of type 'File[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'File'.
> Type 'File[]' is missing the following properties from type 'File': lastModified, name, size, type, and 3 more.  TS2345

вот кот модального окна, ошибка возникает когда я пытаюсь передать input в функцию addSong()

```
 import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Button, Modal } from 'react-bootstrap'



type AddSong = {
   addSong(file:File):void
}




export const AddSong: React.FC<AddSong> = ({addSong}) => {
    const [input, setInput] = useState<File[]>([])
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);


    const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
    
    const handleShow = () => setShow(true);



    const handleChange = (e: any) => {
        setInput(e.target.files[0]);
        console.log(input)
    }


    const UploadFile = () => {
        addSong(input);
        
        setShow(false);

    }

    return (

        <>

            <svg onClick={handleShow} id="plus-icon" fill="#000000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24px" height="24px"><path d="M 11 2 L 11 11 L 2 11 L 2 13 L 11 13 L 11 22 L 13 22 L 13 13 L 22 13 L 22 11 L 13 11 L 13 2 Z" /></svg>

            <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
                <Modal.Header closeButton>
                    <Modal.Title>Добавьте файл</Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>
                <div className="upload-icon">

                    <div className="urlContainer">
                        <input type="file" className="fileInput" onChange={handleChange} />

                    </div>
                </div>
                <Modal.Footer>
                    <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
                        Close
            </Button>
                    <Button variant="primary" onClick={UploadFile}>
                        Save Changes
            </Button>

                </Modal.Footer>
            </Modal>
        </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы указали тип File[]

```
const [input, setInput] = useState<File[]>([])
```

А пытаетесь положить File

```
setInput(e.target.files[0]);
```

Comment: То есть мне надо написать const [input, setInput] = useState<File>()?

Comment: Если хотите хранить только один - useState<File>({}).

Comment: Аргумент типа "{}" нельзя назначить параметру типа "File | (() => File)".
  Тип "{}" не может быть назначен для типа "() => File".
    Тип "{}" не предоставляет соответствия для сигнатуры "(): File".  я совсем недавно начала изучать ts не думал, что будет столько проблем с файлами

Comment: @Bad_m, попробуйте null

Comment: Ошибка пропала только когда я поставил тип any, но функция addSong все странно работает и если я выберу файл то в input с первого раза ничего не записывается, но с этим я уже сам как нибудь буду разбираться